# Why I can't see Instance Class on Application Settings?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have created billed Appengine Application. I can easily configure Instance Class like F1 or F4 on appengine-web.xml by adding F4 but I want to also change instance on the fly without uploading any code. Because on one of my projects I can change Instance Class on Application Settings tab.

What do you think, what is the problem with new project configuration?

This is what I want
[image: This is what I want]

This is what I see
[image: This is what I see]

Comment: Are you the project admin?

Comment: sorry for the dumb questions but its always good to check, then again it's really weird so it might be the smallest detail that's causing this. are you using Master-slave by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken out from the new admin console. All existing frontend applications and new applications created are migrated to modules automatically.

You can see this in the official docs here
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/converting

> With the advent of modules, the frontend is treated like any other
>   module; its performance settings are included in its xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have any configuration problem. You just can't access this configuration tool because of the fairly new [module feature](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/).

Google is slowly migrating everything to the [new admin console](https://console.developers.google.com) and the feature you are trying to access is deprecated since the introduction of the module feature.

I guess that you still see the performance configuration for your other project because it was created before the module feature was introduced.

Comment: Might be but I couldn't find any document that corrects this information.

Comment: it makes sense, but modules has been out for some time now. I don't know how they could still be rolling out features at this point.